# Filter data from array java script?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

in my app I want to filter some database data which is in array.
I have html text field and when user start to type in I want JavaScript function to go through my array and offer user hit words. For example if user start to type "c" function will show him everything what begins with "c" (coca-cola, c....).
Thanks.

Comment: Check out jQuery's Autocomplete : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: It's not that hard to do *(you certainly don't need jQuery)*. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I changed little bit my logic.
I have two arrays(or one two dimensional array, I don't know what is better) and two fields if user start to type in field named by 'name' I want function to offer hit and after user choose something offered fill other field named by 'id' with proper id of that name(that's why I think to use two dimensional array)? Can you help me with this?

Comment: Edit your question to post what you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery's [autocomplete library](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: Ok, that's great, thanks.
Can I ask you a question, I have two arrays(or one two dimensional array, I don't know what is better) and two fields if user start to type in field named by 'name' I want function to offer hit and after user choose something offered fill other field named by 'id' with proper id of that name(that's why I think to use two dimensional array)? Can you help me with this?